# Use twig variable in string

Tags: symfony, twig

For the language selection I want to show the flag of the current active languages.

I get the language variable by:

```
app.request.locale
```

Now I want to use the value in the string of the flag url.

```
<img src="{{ asset('flags/'+app.request.locale+'.png', 'img') }}" />
```

But what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `~` char instead of `+`.